# Disable price field when checkbox is checked (node add form)

Tags: nodes

I would like to disable 2 price fields when a checkbox is checked. This could be easier with webform by I want to implement that on the node add form (admin).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are working on D7 / D8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For D7 you can go for

[Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)

> Define dependencies between fields based on their states and values.
>
> Conditional Fields for Drupal 7 is an user interface to the new States
> API, plus the ability to modify fields appearance and behavior on
> certain conditions when viewing content.

[Field Conditional States](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_conditional_state)

The Field Conditional State module can be used when:

> you have a text field you only want to be enabled when a certain checkbox is checked
>
> you want to show a different set of fields depending on the value(s) selected in a certain select list